# regular expression to match whole word in mongodb

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I want to search the result in MongoDB like in the following scenario.

I have data like `Hello World, I am here.`

My Query is:

```
{"$or": [{"data.title": {"$regex":  search}}]}; //search = Hello
```

So i am searching it using $regex. but the problem is that if i type search = H, then again its returning the data

I want to search on the basis complete word only. (example: Hello or World) not on the basis of Characters (example: H or e)

Comment: You can validate length before doing query, to avoid single char search.
And if you don't want to block single char search, then what is your expected output, empty set ?

Comment: My statement can contain single character word also like "I am your friend" so user can search by "I" also. but it should be complete word of a sentence  not incomplete word or characters for example: instead of "friend" you cant search by "f" or "fri" it should only be search by "friend"

Comment: You can add a space at the end of the search string and start of search string. Pass it with pipe operator.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, its a good idea.

Comment: `{'data.title': {"$regex": ".*{0}.*".format(search)}}` may solve your problem...

The trick here are the .* in the begining and in the end to match the whole word

Answer (score 10):

You can use the \b (word boundary) operator, eg:

```
{"$or": [{"data.title": {"$regex": /\bHello\b/i}}]}
```

In this way, searching for "/\bH\b/" won't match "Hello".

Otherwise, use a $text index on your title field, then do a $text search:

```
{"$or": [{$text:{$search:"Hello"}}]}
```

For more information about text search, look at the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes-text/

Comment: how to implement it for moongoose ?

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy I never used mongoose, but reading the docs, i think you could try with the where condition (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-where, it accepts both regexp or custom query), the setQuery method (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-setQuery) or even with a query helper (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers).