# regular expression to find value in comma separated data

Tags: regex, mongodb, csv

I do have comma separated data, like this:

```
"go,godown,goup,go,ago,agon,aerugos,gone,going,good,goof,goaway,nogo,go"
```

What would be the regular expression if **go** should match as complete word, not as part of any word. Like:

"**go**,godown,goup,**go**,ago,agon,aerugos,gone,going,good,goof,goaway,nogo,**go**"

Tried like this, but it's not exactly what i need:

```
(?<=,|^)(\s*)go(?=\s*,|\s*|$)
```

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `\bgo\b` https://regex101.com/r/GNJvcA/1 ?

Comment: `db.getCollection('videos').find({"synonym": {"$regex": "\bgo\b"}})` i am using it in pymongo query. it's not working as expected. would it be different here ?

Comment: Try to use `//`, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938354/580346

Comment: Also: ready this answer and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483399/580346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\bgo\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNJvcA/1)

`\b` matches word boundary

Comment: thanks, it works well. but it matches in this case as well `...,go down,...` any suggestion to avoid it ?

Comment: You can try: `(:?^|,)(go)(:?$|,)`  https://regex101.com/r/GNJvcA/3. Do you have more cases like that? You had no spaces in the example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to have a complete word match, use \b:

```
\bgo\b      -- 'go' word
```